# Swift Siesta access response raw data

Tags: swift, pdf, raw-data, siesta-swift

I've in my API a method that return a content of PDF file.

How can I access the raw data of response in success callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Siesta responses start out as raw data (in the form of the Foundation type `Data`), then run through the [transformer pipeline](http://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/guide/pipeline/).

The default transformer pipeline parses JSON, text, and images based on the `Content-type` header sent by the server. That list doesn’t include PDF, so if your server is sending a content type of `application/pdf` (or anything that isn’t a JSON, text, or image content type), the response will still be raw `Data` at the end of the pipeline:

```
request.onSuccess { entity in
  guard let data = entity.content as? Data else {
    print("Huh, got mystery response:", entity.content)
    return
  }
  // do stuff with data
}
```

If you aren’t getting `Data` — if the code above says “huh” — then something in your pipeline is transforming the response. You can use Siesta’s verbose logging to figure out what:

```
Siesta.LogCategory.enabled = LogCategory.detailed
```

Look in the log output for:

- `Added config`, which is logged when something adds a transformer to the pipeline,
- the `pipeline` section of the `Resulting configuration` before the request in question, which shows all the transformers that may apply to the response, and
- `Applied transformer` and `Response after pipeline` to see how the actual server response gets transformed.