# When using Siesta to make an API post, the request method is returning a "Cannot parse server response" error

Tags: ios, json, siesta-swift

I am having issues parsing the response from an API call using Siesta for iOS. After I post the JSON, it fails trying to parse the response.

```
    resource("/SaveEmailAddress").request(.post, json: SaveEmailAddress.toDictionary()).onSuccess { (entity) in
        completion(entity, nil)
        }.onFailure{ (error) in
            completion(nil, error)
    }
```

The API is only returning "Success" in the body.

```
:status: 200 
cache-control: private 
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319 
x-powered-by: ASP.NET 
date: Tue, 23 Oct 2018 03:35:42 GMT 
content-length: 9

"Success"
```

It is my understanding that "Success" is valid JSON, however, because it is not an array or a dictionary, Siesta is throwing a "Cannot parse server response" error.

```
error (Siesta.RequestError)
userMessage = (String) "Cannot parse server response"
httpStatusCode = (int?)nil
entity = (Siesta.Entity<Any>?)nil
```

When I enable the detailed logs for Siesta, it gives me the following error:

> Error: RequestError(userMessage: "Cannot parse server response",
>   httpStatusCode: nil, entity: nil, cause:
>   Optional(Siesta.RequestError.Cause.JSONResponseIsNotDictionaryOrArray(actualType:
>   NSTaggedPointerString)), timestamp: 562010225.337566)

Is there a way to force Siesta to accept it as a valid JSON response?  If so, what steps specifically do I need to do to make that happen? I have seen other threads recommend adding an extension which has already been done, but isn't working for me.

```
extension String: Siesta.JSONConvertible { }
```

Comment: Do you mean that the server is returning the characters `"Success"` as the body, including the quotation marks?

Comment: Yes.  The body only contains "Success" with the quotes.  I modified the response above to reflect the message being returned.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to parse the String response to a Dictionary or Array. Did you set up the transformer pipeline to do so? Consult [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307224/swift-siesta-access-response-raw-data), and [this issue](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/issues/176)

Comment: I looked at the other two posts and am not sure how to implement. I am not getting a dictionary or an array back which is the problem.  I am only receiving the message "Success" back.  "Success" is technically valid Json even though it isn't in a dictionary or array format. Most of my other calls have an array or dictionary.  This one does not. I am not sure how to solve this.