# Siesta JSON Response

Tags: ios, json, swift, siesta-swift

I have set up an API that gives a JSON response as follows:

```
{
                "key1": "success",
                "key2": {
                    "int_val": 5,
                    "str_val": "email",
                }
}
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307224/swift-siesta-access-response-raw-data), yet still do not understand how I can access `key1` properly. I have tried to decode the data in the transformer through `[String : Any]`, which throws an ambiguous type error: "Type of expression is ambiguous".

So how can I read the response with Siesta in the code below?

```
service.resource("").request(.post, json: userJSON).onSuccess{ entity in
        guard let data = entity.content as? Data else {
            return
        }
        print(data)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Decodable`

```
struct Root:Decodable ( 
  let key1:String
  let key2:InnerItem
}

struct InnerItem:Decodable { 
  let intVal:Int
  let strVal:String
}
```

---

```
do {
    let decoder =  JSONDecoder() 
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let res = decoder.decode(Root.self,from:data)
    print(res.key1) 
}
catch {

    print(error)
 }
```

Comment: That's a typo when I copy and pasted. And ok, I figured this would be the case. Appreciate the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Parse the **Data** object as a **Dictionary**  which represents your JSON response.

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String : Any]

if let key1 = json["key1"] as? String {
    print(key1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [sample project included with Siesta](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/tree/master/Examples/GithubBrowser) has [lots of example of configuring JSON decoding to models](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/blob/master/Examples/GithubBrowser/Source/API/GithubAPI.swift#L71-L103). For example, if you have the `Root` and `InnerItem` types from @Sh_Khan’s answer:

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder() 
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

service.configureTransformer(“/somepath") {
    try jsonDecoder.decode([Root].self, from: $0.content)
}
```

The important difference from the other answers is the use of [`service.configureTransformer`](http://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Classes/Service.html#/s:6Siesta7ServiceC20configureTransformer_14requestMethods7atStage6action19onInputTypeMismatch15transformErrors11description16contentTransformyAA31ConfigurationPatternConvertible_p_SayAA13RequestMethodOGSgAA08PipelineH3KeyCAA0xH0V14MutationActionOAA015ResponseContentD0V0klM6ActionOyxq__GSbSSSgq_SgAA6EntityVyxGKctr0_lF). Instead of parsing the response every time you use it, configuring a transformer means that it is parsed just *once*, and everyone sees the parsed result — every `onSuccess`, everyone who looks at `resource.latestData`, etc.